# How to attach listeners to the remote page in an electron app

Tags: javascript, electron, dom-events

I have an electron app that will just wrap a remote page while adding some extra features. With the following code the page loads and works. The problem is that it is missing usual browser shortcuts for controlling the history navigation and page zooming.

Thus I like to add those shortcuts manually. I fail when it comes to find the document or window of the remote page to attach event listeners to.

**How do I attach keydown (and others) event listeners to the remote page?**

```
const {app, shell, BrowserWindow} = require('electron');

let mainWindow;

function createWindow () {
  // Create the browser window.
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1024,
    height: 786,
  });

  mainWindow.setMenu(null);
  mainWindow.setTitle('My app – Connecting…');
  mainWindow.loadURL('https://some.url.somwhere');

  mainWindow.webContents.on('did-finish-load', () => {

    // How to get the window/document here? Both are undefined
    window.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
      if (e.key === 'ArrowLeft' && e.altKey) {
        webview.history.back();
      } else if (e.key === 'ArrowRight' && e.altKey) {
        webview.history.forward();
      }
    });

  });

  // Emitted when the window is closed.
  mainWindow.on('closed', () => {
    mainWindow = null
  })
}

app.on('ready', createWindow);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mainWindow.webContents.on('did-finish-load', () => {
    mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()
    mainWindow.webContents.executeJavaScript(`window.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
      if (e.key === 'ArrowLeft' && e.altKey) {
        console.log('Alt + <-')
        window.history.back();
      } else if (e.key === 'ArrowRight' && e.altKey) {
        console.log('Alt + ->')
        window.history.forward();
      }
    });`)
  })
```